# How can i use an int instead of using Integer?

Tags: java, string, int

```
for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
    boolean pen15 = false;
    String s = in.next();

    int cur = Integer.valueOf(s.charAt(0));
    int k = -1;
    if(s.length()==1){
        System.out.println("AD "+s);
        pen15 = true;
    }
}
```

How can I cast an `int` instead of using `Integer`? I tried using
`int cur = (int).valueOf(s.charAt(0));`, but it doesn't even compile.

Comment: `int cur = Character.digit(s.charAt(0), 10);` **or** `int cur = s.charAt(0) - '0';`

Comment: `Integer` is a wrapper class. It has methods. `int` is a primitive. It does not have methods.

Comment: Integer is just a wrapper, but the Integer object it return can be casted to int with no problem, i think that it's neither necessary to use en explicit cast, but if it's not that case, just use `int cur = (int) Integer.valueOf(s.charAt(0));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you really want. An integer value for the character? Or its decimal number in ASCII table?

```
String s = "12345";
int cur = Integer.valueOf(s.charAt(0)); //49
cur = (int)s.charAt(0); //49
cur = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0)); //1
cur = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(0))); //1
cur = Character.digit(s.charAt(0), 10); //1
cur = s.charAt(0) - '0'; //1
```

Comment: I was just trying to cast it with `int`. But this works fine too: `int cur = s.charAt(0) - '0';`

Comment: For getting the codepoint, even the cast is obsolete, just `int cur = s.charAt(0);` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the code like this:

```java
int cur = s.charAt(0);
```